# Proper way to implement R parallel processing with batchtools on local windows machine with clusterFunctionsSocket()

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am trying to implement a parallel-processing routine using R batchtools on multicore Windows machine. The machine has 448GB of RAM with 2 sockets, 12 core processors (24 cores total).

I am trying to implement a parallel processing routine using 'batchtools' in R, which has the cluster function `makeClusterFunctionsSocket()` wherein 'Jobs are spawned asynchronously using the package snow'. The function correctly detects all 24 cores, however when I submit jobs and look at CPU and memory utilization it appears that not all CPUs are being utilized (utilization maxes at around 20% for very intensive jobs).

Batchtools also provides functionality for 'inner Parallelization' when submitting jobs. So **my question is, to fully implement a parallel routine, do I need to implement the inner parallelization if I'm already specifying batchtools to create a socket cluster?**

If I understand correctly, the following implementation should submit jobs to each available core, so that 24 jobs should be running simultaneously.

Here is an example routine with my current implementation:

```
##---- Required Packages
library(batchtools)

##---- Create a temporary registry item
reg = makeRegistry(file.dir = paste("example_project","Registry",sep="_"), seed = 42)
reg$cluster.functions=makeClusterFunctionsSocket() #correctly identifies all 24 cores

##---- An example function

get_random_mean2 <- function(mu, sigma, ...){
  x <- rnorm(100, mean = mu, sd = sigma)
  c(sample_mean = mean(x), sample_sd = sd(x))
}

##---- Set up the batch processing jobs
##---- grid should contain columns for all desired variable combinations
par_grid <- expand.grid(mu = -5:5, sigma = seq(3, 33, 10), nrep = 1:1000)

##---- Clear the R registry
clearRegistry(reg)

##---- Create jobs
jobs <- batchMap(fun = get_random_mean2,args = par_grid)
jobs$chunk <- chunk(jobs$job.id, chunk.size = 10)


getJobTable()
getStatus()

##---- Submit Jobs
options(batchtools.progress = FALSE)
done <- batchtools::submitJobs(jobs,resources= list(memory = 80000),reg=reg)
waitForJobs()
```

However, looking at resource monitor I see something closer to the image below, which shows 24 R processes, but most CPUs are parked?

[image: 24 R processes currently running, total CPU utilization still at 20%]
[image]